# Push Git repo from origin to mirror without download to local

Tags: git, mirror

#### Have a Git repo on one remote server, need to mirror to other server, with no local copy. Possible?

**current solution** with local copy

```
## Init once
git clone --bare url/origin-server/repo
git remote add mirror url/mirror-server/repo
## usual procedure
git fetch origin --force --prune '*:*'
git push --mirror mirror
```

**Wanna use something like**

```
git remote-mirror url/origin-server/repo url/mirror-server/repo
```

with no local copy required.

Comment: currently there is no such feature in git. The closest you can get is a "fork" on the same remote machine. The reason is that "mirror" hosts must support that feature. There is currently no git server frontend that supports a "remote fork" as you request it.

Answer (score 0):

If you can ssh to the `mirror-server` you can clone there:

```
ssh mirror-server git clone url/origin-server/repo
```

If you cannot ssh but both repositories are hosted at Github or Gitlab you can use their API ([Github](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/forks/#create-a-fork), [Gitlab](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/projects.html#fork-project)) to fork the repo.

In a general case (no ssh, no API) you are out of luck and intermediate local bare repo is the only way.